# North and South - which is it?

Tags: talmud-gemara, korban, kedusha-holiness

1) The Torah says that North, צפון, is the place for bringing kodshei kodoshim, especially-holy korbonos - like olos. For a list, see perek Eizehu Mekoman in Zevachim.
2) Chazal also say (Bava Basra 25b), הרוצה להחכים ידרים, הרוצה להעשיר יצפין - One who wishes to become wise, let him turn slightly to the south when he prays [the Menorah in the Mishkan was in the south]. One who wishes to become wealthy should turn slightly to the north [the Shulchan in the Mishkan was in the north.] So here south represents the spiritual, north the physical.
3) Zevachim 116a, it brings the verse (Shir Hashirim 4:16) עורי צפון ובואי תימן (Maharsha - awake, North; arrive, South). The gemara learns from there that Bnei Noach are not allowed to bring shelamim, and therefore Israel was only allowed to do so after the Torah was given. (Maharsha - awaken, old olos that people could bring before. Come anew, shelamim, that can be brought now. Or see Rashi.) Israel's greatness meant being allowed "in the south", and being allowed to actually eat korbonos. [Note that some korbonos that are eaten (chatas, asham) are still kodesh kodoshim and brought in the north as well.]

And now I'm confused. Which represents the spiritual, the north or the south?

Comment: Maybe that’s the point – the north represents bring the material into the spiritual, while the south represents that which already is? I mean, I’m not completely convinced that each direction has a trait associated with it, but based on these sources that would be my gut reaction if I had to assign one to each.

Comment: We have the concept of The menorah and The Aron. The Aaron represents Torah shebal Peh and the Menorah represents Torah shebactav. The Aron also represents all the heavenly lights that come into this world. The Aaron in the Kodesh hakodoshim also has the Ketuvim were The kedushah was. Hashem is perfect and can not change but we can. The menorah represents how we understand and add to this perfect Torah. The south represents what was.

Comment: I have no source for this but I believe that spiritualness for a person must be worked upon. We are not born perfect but have to work hard and strive for an understanding. We can't deny that the kodesh hakadoshim is in the north, but for the average person. They are not perfect and have to wor hard, they symbolize with the Menorah, human effort the Torah Shebal peh.

Comment: Samarias in the north and Judeans in the south. Spirituality lies everywhere. God is imminent.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion (Some of the comments leaned in this direction as well):
Rav Hirsch at the beginning of Vayikra talks about צפון, the north. If I understand him correctly, he says that it does represent the physical - and therefore some korbonos represent the person *sacrificing*, subjugating, his physical side.
But there is a higher level. The Ramchal in Mesilas Yesharim explains the idea of Kedushah  (holiness) at the end of his sefer. Prishus (separating from the physical) is an earlier stage. Once a person has achieved prishus and grown in his control over his physical desires, *then* he can be ready to reach kedushah. Instead of just suppression and control, the person can reach the stage of *using* the physical in service to the spiritual. Instead of the two being in conflict, they become two parts of a whole, and the person's use of the physical becomes part of his overall avodah. - according to the Ramchal.
It could be that the "North" is the only kind of korbon appropriate to a Ben Noach: controlling the physical. But the gemara in Zevachim doesn't say that Bnei Noach are North and Yisrael is the South instead. It says that Yisrael is on the South *in addition* (Rashi). The new level is to be able to handle both. Chazal say that this explains the name "shlamim": a korbon that makes "shalom", represents completeness: Hashem, cohen, yisroel.
[Advertisement] In my sefer, in Parshas Terumah, I list a number of parallels between the Aron Hakodesh and the Shulchan - and a different set of parallels between the Keruvim and the Menorah. These are different levels. In the outer Heichal, the Menorah and the Shulchan represent two independent forces. You can't turn both ways!
But in the Holy of Holies, the two vessels are combined into a single vessel where both forces are one, as their source is One.